# Add Server between current wireless router and new router

Tags: wireless, networking, server, internet, dhcp

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 Server with a wireless router attached. I would like to connect it to my modem/wireless router via the wireless interface in a transparent manner. My goal is to use the server to log some netflows and maybe run squid between the modem and wireless.

Would this be done via a network bridge? I'm not sure how to handle dhcp. Would it be possible to use dhcp from the wireless router to issue IPs from the access point? Or would disabling dhcp on the modem/wireless router, assigning the server a static IP and turning on dhcp on the attached router. Any thought on how to do this would be appreciated.

Internet <-> Modem/Wireless router <-> Server <-> Wireless Router <-> Devices

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless router should have a bridge mode but the setup is different according the the manufacturer and some won;t bridge between vendors (you may be able to run DD-WRT if you run into this issue).

In Bridge mode you generally disable DHCP on the "client" router and let it be served from the master.

Alternatively you can purchase a USB wifi adapter for as little as $6 on Newegg.